# How can i store data of Firebase push Notification locally with sharedPreference

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

I want to store Firebase Pushnotification data locally in my application. like i have done some Native code in android to open the application from background or kill when device get the firebase push notification. from that the application can be opened without interaction when they get notification but when i am storing that notification data in sharedpreference its getting lost some how but its working fine in **_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler** method but when i try to get it in another screen its getting null please anyone have suggetion how can i done this without lost the data?.

**this is background method where i can easily get data.**

```
    Future _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
      RemoteMessage message,
    ) async {
      LocalNotificationService.initializedd();
      LocalNotificationService.createAndDisplayNotification(message);
      newPrefs =await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      newPrefs?.reload();
      newPrefs?.setString("string_data", message.data['string_data']);
      var stringData= newPrefs?.get("string_data"); 
    }
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,);
```

**this is the code where i lost the data sometimes and it is in another screen when application gets open from background or terminate state.**

```
newPrefs!.containsKey("string_data")?print("Contain"):print("DoesnotContain");
var stringData= newPrefs?.get("string_data");
```

Comment: why not create a model use sqflite database to store notification i used sqflite database to store notification